# Defer evaluation on all computed properties in Knockout?

Tags: knockout.js

I am trying to make a base class for all my viewmodels so I for instance can check "isDirty" on the root-vm and have it check the entire tree of vms (while avoiding circular dependencies).

When doing this I realized that the order of ko-properties is very important because a computed property set up its subscriptions based on what other properties exists at the time of creating the property. So if I would put a isDirty-computed like the one below in a base-class it would always initialize before the properties it depens on even exists. Anyway, to cut it short, I noticed I could use the deferEvaluation to remedy this problem.

My question are:

Are there any drawbacks of using deferEvaluation on all computed properties? Why is'nt this behaviour true by default? When would I need it set to false?

Can I do this isDirty-property better? Any suggestions on improving it or doing it in some other way?

And alternatively, is there any way to explicitly disable initialization of computed properties until the entire object with all its properties is created, and then run it in some way. I mean the only problem for me is that the subscriptions are set up before all properties are in place.

Note: I'm using KO Lite Tools for dirty-tracking

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.isDirty = ko.computed(function () {
        for (var p in self) {
            if (self[p].isDirty) {
                if (self[p].isDirty()) return true;
            }
            else if (self[p].subscribe && self[p].push) { // assuming ko.observableArray
                for (var i = 0, j = self[p]().length; i < j; i++) {
                    if (self[p]()[i].isDirty) {
                        if (self[p]()[i].isDirty()) return true;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }, this, { deferEvaluation: true });
}
```

Note: Just noticed that this code will fail if I have another computed property that is depending on isDirty. This was kind of expected but also unfortunate. It would be great if I instead could delay and force all subscriptions to after object creation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you found out, normally, a `ko.computed` is calculated and dependencies are detected when the computed is first created.

When using `deferEvaluation`, dependency detection for a `ko.computed` is not performed immediately, but instead is performed each time the value is requested.

This provides a powerful mechanism for dynamically varying the dependencies, but does result in increased overhead.

Ryan talks about this a little [on this page](http://www.knockmeout.net/2011/06/10-things-to-know-about-knockoutjs-on.html) (scroll down to section 3 - The basic rules of computed observables):

---

Would it be possible to structure your code so that the `ko.computed` values are defined *after* the other properties are created?

If your main problem is in the dirty flag tracking, you could set up a beginInit() and endInit() methods in your base VM and set up your isDirty computed inside the endInit().  You or may not need the beginInit(), but it provides a nice hook for consistency and may be useful later on.

Of course, the derived VM needs to call the base init methods before and after setting up its observables.  I'm not sure what your current strategy for creating the derived VM is - I'm typically use a factory to provide prototypal inheritance, and I have this sort of control over the initialization timing.

An simpler alternative to the beginInit() and endInit(), is to simply provide an initProperties() function in the derived classes where all the properties are defined, and call that method from the base VM, then set up your isDirty computed.

Comment: I ended up using a endInit-method called at the end of each class construction. I also had to provide the explicit name of the class that calls endInit so that only the "top most" class of a inheritance chain is actually doing the endInit. It's not ideal but it works.

Answer (score 2):

If your `computed` is truly a computation, then there is generally no harm in deferring evaluation until someone actually needs the value.

In cases, where your `computed` actually performs some action either as a by-product of getting a value or as its only purpose, then deferring evaluation may not be the right choice. In some cases, a `computed` can be used as a way to subscribe to multiple observables and perform an action when any of them change rather than simply returning a value.

There is not a way to disable initialization until the entire object has been created other than by deferring evaluation and accessing it later, unless you were to do something like create your computed in a `setTimeout`. This could cause errors though, if other code expects it to be there.

Comment: do you have a concrete example of when I would need `a way to subscribe to multiple observables and perform an action when any of them change rather than simply returning a value`. I have quite a few `computed` that are giving pretty complicated calculated values, but I'm not aware of any of them that would break if deferred was true. I'm considering a helper to create a defered=true computed, but don't want to without fully understanding the situation in which it would be bad

Comment: @Simon_Weaver - this would be a case where the computed is created simply to react to changes to one or more observables rather than returning a value. For example, you can create a computed that accesses all of the observables in an object (`ko.toJS(this)` would do the trick) and calls some type of save to the database when any change. So, the computed would be a simple way to achieve this vs. attempting to create a manual subscription against every observable in the object hierarchy.

Comment: ok so basically you're saying I'd already be aware if I was doing this ;-) I guess I still don't fully understand why 'deferred=true' isn't the default. I suppose it's nice to just hit every deferred after the object is constructed to immediately expose any errors, but sometimes I run into cases where I want to suppress them all (as the mapping plugin does when it maps an object)

Comment: @Simon_Weaver - `deferred = true` would be a decent default now, but would be a breaking change, which we try very hard to avoid. I think that you have the right thought process with this and a helper to create a deferred computed would be a fine choice.

Comment: ok that makes it a lot clearer now. I think a helper would be nice for certain cases, but I'm trying to avoid it in general. the situation I was in was using the `create` callback in the ko.mapping plugin which created a `new Order(options.data)` which in turn 'mapped itself'. the mapping plugin was magically suppressing all the `deferred`s for me (which I hadn't realize) so when I went to just manually create a `new Order(...)` by myself it all exploded on me. but it's all fixed now :) thanks!